# Proving that $Rad ( \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_{i})= \bigoplus_{i \in I} Rad (M_{i})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I want to prove that $ Rad ( \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_{i})= \bigoplus_{i \in I} Rad (M_{i})$, according to how Kasch sketched the proof in Modules and Rings in Corollary 9.1.5. I got the gist of the proof but there are a couple of steps that are a little bit confusing to me.

Suppose that $M = \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_{i}$. So, for proving that $Rad(M) \subseteq \bigoplus_{i \in I} Rad (M_{i})$ let's take $m \in Rad(M)$. Then $m = \sum_{i \in I} m_{i} \in Rad(M)$. Now taking the projection $\pi_{i}: M \to M_{i}$, where $\pi_{i}(m) = m_{i} \in Rad(M_{i})$. The part I don't get from this proof is the equality at the beginning $m = \sum_{i \in I} m_{i} \in Rad(M)$. I mean where are this $m_{i}$ at the beginning, I guess it has something to do with the fact that the radical of the module is the sum of all superfluous submodules of a module but I'm not quite sure.

To prove that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} Rad (M_{i}) \subseteq Rad(M)$. Since $M_{i} \leq  M$ we got that $Rad(M_{i}) \leq Rad(M)$. Therefore $\sum_{i \in I} Rad(M_{i}) \leq  Rad(M) $. Then the book states that $\sum_{i \in I} Rad(M_{i}) = \bigoplus_{i \in I} Rad (M_{i}) \leq Rad (M)$ finishing the last part of the proof. What I don't get is why $\sum_{i \in I} Rad(M_{i}) = \bigoplus_{i \in I} Rad (M_{i})$, is there any propery I'm missing here?  Anyway, thanks for reading and helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

(1) By definition of coproduct, every element in $M$ has the form $m = \sum_{i\in I} m_i$, where only finite $m_i$ can be nonzero. To make the proof complete, you can prove the following lemma.

**Lemma 1.** If $N$ and $P$ are $R$-modules, and $f: N \longrightarrow P$ is a surjective module morphism. Then $f(Rad(N)) \subset Rad(P)$.

Proof sketch: This comes from the fact that $N/ \ker f \cong P$.

(2) The sum $\oplus_{i\in I} Rad(M_i)$ is a direct sum in $M$. This is a basic property in the theory of modules as showed in the following proposition.

**Proposition.** If $\{N_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of submodules of an $R$-module $N$, and for any finite set of indices $J = \{i_1, \dots, i_j\}$, $N_{i_1} \cap (\sum_{k \in J-\{ i _1\}} N_{i_k} ) = 0$. Then $\sum_{i \in I} N_i$ is the direct sum $\oplus_{i\in I} N_i$.

Comment: Tell me  if I'm wrong but I think that for (1) $m=\sum_{i \in I} m_{i}$ comes from the fact that $m$ belongs to a coproduct, but coproducts and direct sums are the same in modules. Otherwise I don't see how the Lemma you stated and the first isomorphism implies  $m=\sum_{i \in I} m_{i}$ . For (2), what is the complete statement? for every direct summands $M_{i}, M_{j}$ such that $i \neq j$ we got that $Rad(M_{i}) \cap Rad (M_{j}) = 0$? Or for any arbitrary subomodules $M_{i}, M_{j}$ in $M$? I cannot prove any of these statements :( @Functor

Comment: @Sok. For (1), the lemma is applied to the surjective morphism $\pi_i$
 in your question. For(2),  I have added a basic proposition.

Comment: Great! (1) is perfectly clear. But (2) is a little bit convoluted. I recall now the Proposition you stated, and I think it's an equivalence right? I mean, we have the other implication as well. So it boils down to prove that $Rad(M_{i_1}) \cap (\sum_{k \in J-\{ i _1\}} Rad(M_{i_k} )) = 0$. But this is not trivial. The fact that the proposition is valid for a finite se of indices $J$ also bugs me, because it's never stated that $I$ is finite. $I$ is an arbitrary set finite or not.

Comment: The set $I$ is arbitrary. But by definition of coproduct, every element in $M$ is in a finite sum of $M_i$. So $M_{i_1} \cap \sum_{k\in J-\{i_1\}} M_{i_k} = 0$ implies the equality of $Rad(M_i)$.